# how can fetch data with different collection in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

First of all, the user creates a business and then to able to add a schedule of business and other data related to business in different collections that save with businessId. my question is, I have an API business-detail fetch all data from the different collections and send it to the client, how can I achieve this? If there is any mistake please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `$lookup` aggregate pipeline or just make Four DB call and fetch the desired results and restructure and return the response in the API.